# anything alternative to VMCI technology in ESXi <5.5 for ESXi 6.0?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have written two applications which I should place them on two different virtual machines. These two apps, need a fast communication between them. as I needed more than 1Gbps, CPU friendly link, I searched and realized that there is VMCI available for ESXi servers older than 5.5. I don't like wasting 2 cores for a communication inside an ESXi server. there should be an alternative in ESXi 6.0. so if my guess is true, guide me where and how I can use that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a vmxnet3 adapter, current virtual hardware version and you'll see a virtual 10Gbps link.

Answer (score 0):

Just run them on the same host.

Comment: They are on the same host, and link is 1Gbps.

Comment: That the link is 1Gbps is irrelevant - when they're on the same machine, and using the VMXNET3 adapter they'll talk as quickly as possible, often up to 10Gbps or more.